# TS reuse this.constructor in parent method

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, subclassing, type-assertion

I have a base `Message` class and an subclass `SpecializedMessaged` for extra features

```
class Message {
    constructor(
        readonly content: string
    ) { }
    edit(replacement: string) {
        return new Message(replacement)
    }
}

class SpecializedMessage extends Message {
    extra() {}
}
```

Since the `.edit()` logic will be the same for `Message` and all sub-classes, I implement it once in base `Message` to be inherited. Immutability is important in my use case, so a new instance must be returned every edit.

However,

```
        return new Message(replacement)
```

will result in an undesirable cast of child instances back to the base type

```
let message = new SpecializedMessage('hello')
message.extra() // works
message = message.edit('world') // message now instanceof `Message` instead of `SpecializedMessage`
message.extra() // fails, `Message` lacks `.extra()`
```

I attempt to solve this using `this.constructor` to automatically use the constructor of whatever class instance is being used

```
class Message {
    // ...
    edit(replacement: string) {
        return new this.constructor(replacement)
    }
}
```

but TS alerts

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)
(property) Object.constructor: Function
```

despite the code working in vanilla JavaScript.

I am able to quiet the errors by casting `this.constructor` `as` a constructor

```
class Message {
    // ...
    edit(replacement: string) {
        const ctor = this.constructor as { new (content: string): Message}
        return new ctor(replacement)
    }
}
```

but want a solution that doesn't require an extra step.

Why is TS rejecting my usage of `this.constructor()`? How can I solve it?

I understand that the approach is inherently unsafe so long as subclasses can have unique constructor signatures, but that doesn't seem to be what TS is concerned with from the error message.

Comment: `this.constructor` is UNSAFE! You are relying on child classes to have the exact same signature as the parent class, which is safe to say, not going to happen most of the time.

Comment: @kelsny I realized that and will go with a different approach, but that doesn't seem to be what the error message is concerned with. TS is seemingly failing to recognize that the expression is constructable, even if unsafe.

Comment: No, `this.constructor` is not **guaranteed** to be a constructor, as insane that sounds. The type of `this.constructor` is `Function` to be as general as possible. If there is no construct signature, then it can't be called as a constructor.

Comment: @kelsny Doesn't every class definition have a built-in constructor if none is specified?

Comment: @kelsny That's just TypeScript's inability to properly express the type of `.constructor`. It really is the class constructor in all well-defined cases. As for subclasses not implementing a compatible constructor signature, that needs to be communicated clearly in the subclassing contract, but can easily be expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841408/infer-class-constructor-arguments-from-instance-of-class-in-typescript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498198/polymorphic-call-of-this-constructor, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74356750/how-can-i-make-typescript-aware-of-classinstance-constructor, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638771/how-can-i-create-a-new-instance-of-a-class-using-this-from-within-method

Comment: "*I want a solution that doesn't require an extra step.*" - what do you mean by "extra step" here? The temporary variable? You can just inline that if you want. There's really nothing wrong with using a type assertion here. Just `return new (this.constructor as typeof Message)(replacement);`.

Answer (score 1):

---

---

***Edit / Note** ... due to some of **@Bergi's** comments and an additional one from **@TmTron***

Bergi's and TmTron's proposed [type assertions of `this.constructor as typeof Message` and `as typeof this` as return type of cause are the golden path](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCmUwHN7QN4ChrWAewDsIAXAJwFdhi9SAKbHaU+MAE0JAE9dDj4DiALmglSASwLIGASgwMAvg3isxxWswAO4YPAC2-ISLITksrI2gB6S03jFypAtALwA7tFrEAFmIgA6fCIySmpSaEhoYk4NeDwAMzhECBR4aXV4LTAdfQFpAG4GHGZ7R2c3D29fAMJREJpwmCiY+MSkVDTNbT0DWQim2ITKiAKcRUVMUEgYAGUY4DEwEDEAL2UENrR4AA8+AlYYdeTUORxtsjBaMzHMCZriaFZ4OLByEGJYCGRoAF4y90OUrQAESPZ6ve76DZA-K3IIiOYLEAfL6-FzuWbweaLFZrJKAoEQBGLaCQo7waEFWEQPAgeB+EB4ZD0HCEzGI5F+ZSqWgAA04dnCBDw3ngYQAJOh4WzFhzArt7vIedJqgIDJgYYFqbT6YzmVKsUjPpyVGo+QKwEKReLJayDbLeAZoIrZBISBadC0Aah1QVNTS6QymQxbeyjVzTfz7hbhV5RdAJfrQ8gVfKnUroK7iO6BtAMQacawvfAfTc-drA3rQS83hzw7zI4KY3GE1XwfbVQI08q5WqNTV-TqgzhWzWwyb6+bLbHrQ8ntX3kae53nRmgtnPXjvX2iAOKwwRwvk3WzVGp83JQf26mV5n1wk84iC0WS1Td7qGP0WiGZWPuSfG1a8Y2kShrJkuCpKpyOykGAPqWAAVK+5bvjgn4JJev4RpOTYzt+oEpo6zpQecPrwZYmBAA) one should walk.

The OP's implementation would change slightly to ...

```
class Message {
  constructor(
    readonly content: string
  ) {
  }
  edit(replacement: string) {
    return new (this.constructor as typeof Message)(replacement) as typeof this;
  }
}

class SpecializedMessage extends Message {
  extra() {}
}
```

---

---

... *original answer* ...

[An implementation like](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-S6c0qO2rvbO2eXOYPFsPR1HPjHQXGE0A) ...

```
class Message {
  constructor(
    readonly content: string,
    public messageType = new.target,
  ) {
  }
  edit(replacement: string) {
    return new this.messageType(replacement)
  }
}

class SpecializedMessage extends Message {
  extra() {}
}
```

... which makes use of [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) does not raise any compiler warnings.

The above code provided in its vanilla flavor works as intended by the OP and looks like this ...

```js
class Message {
  constructor(content, messageType = new.target) {
    this.content = content;
    this.messageType = messageType;
  }
  edit(replacement) {
    return new this.messageType(replacement);
  }
}
class SpecializedMessage extends Message {
  extra() {}
}
const defaultMsg = new Message("default message");
const specialMsg = new SpecializedMessage("special message");

console.log(
  specialMsg.edit(`yet another ${ specialMsg.content }`).content
);
console.log(
  specialMsg.edit(`yet another ${ specialMsg.content }`) instanceof Message
);
console.log(
  specialMsg.edit(`yet another ${ specialMsg.content }`) instanceof SpecializedMessage
);

console.log(
  defaultMsg.edit(`yet another ${ defaultMsg.content }`).content
);
console.log(
  defaultMsg.edit(`yet another ${ defaultMsg.content }`) instanceof Message
);
console.log(
  defaultMsg.edit(`yet another ${ defaultMsg.content }`) instanceof SpecializedMessage
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do you make `messageType` a constructor parameter?

Comment: @Bergi ... because I was curious about how to solve the OP's problem of referring within the base-class implementation to a current (sub-)type's constructor without TS warnings but also not using  type definition magic and type assertion(s).

Comment: @Bergi ... I did not assume either that hacking the OP's code like that would be accepted/tolerated by the TS compiler settings at the official TypeScript's playground page. Your proposed assertion of `this.constructor as typeof Message` of cause is the golden path one should walk.

Comment: No, I meant why not write `this.messageType = new.target;` in the constructor instead of adding a default-initialised parameter?

Comment: @Bergi ... ahh, because a more explicit, cleaner syntax does raise a lot of different type warnings depending on how one is going to define or not define the type of `messageType`. Therefore I consider the (accidentally discovered) unnoticed default initialization syntax a blind spot of the compiler.

Comment: You should also add `as typeof this` to the return expression of `edit()`, so that the return type is okay: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCmUwHN7QN4ChrWAewDsIAXAJwFdhi9SAKbHaU+MAE0JAE9dDj4DiALmglSASwLIGASgwMAvg3isxxWswAO4YPAC2-ISLITksrIybxi5UgWgF4Ad2i1iACzEQAdPiJlK1KTQkNDEnBrweABmcIgQKPDS6vBaYDr6ArIhYRHRoR4QANwKmIqYoJAwAMoRwGJgIGIAXsoISKjQ8AAefASsMG3xHeadPaRgtGaKZb4k0KzwUWDkIMSwEMjQALz2TrHt8LQARAtLK8TQ+gdH0sWzFxC19SDrmzsOzjXwdQ3NrXEJY6Pb7PS4A1A3YrlQhzZSqZTbERPBqvLxwtQAcnRygxt2hfk6Kj4rAAomMwIjsaw0eSoUA)

Comment: @TmTron ... thank you, seems to be the most practical solution is a team effort.